# Leading Question Mark causes Eclipse "No resource found that matches the given name" Error

Tags: android, eclipse, string, compiler-errors

In my strings.xml file, I have:

```
<string name="menus_feedback">?Feedback</string>
```

and I get the eclipse error:

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'menus_feedback' with value '?Feedback').

If I remove the leading question mark:

```
<string name="menus_feedback">Feedback</string>
```

it's fine.   Any clues as to why this occurs?   Eclipse Helios Release 2.

n.b.  Was going to use leading question mark just to indicate we need a translation for the string.

Comment: try double quote it "?"Feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enclose the whole text in double quotes

Comment: This solves it.  May never understand why, as it's "just" a string.

Comment: In Android, the character "?" when used in a resource file means it's a reference to a resource value in the currently applied theme, so I'm guessing it's being treated as a special character.